# Dictionary verb or verb stem before noun

Tags: translation

What's the difference between dictionary verb + noun and verb stem + noun? Why would you use one as opposed to the other?
For example, 飲む人 vs 飲み人.

Comment: I don't have time to post a complete answer right now, but I know you will receive some.  But this is a ***CRUCIAL*** concept you need to learn to be successful in Japanese.

Comment: I still don't understand. I learned direct-style verbal + noun in class (my class used a very unconventional textbook), but I don't understand the usage of verb stem (I'm not sure what you think the stem refers to because even my new textbook uses the word "stem" to refer to the masu-form without the masu) + noun or how it compares to dictionary form of a verb + noun. How would verb stem + noun normally be translated? I'm reading a short story, and it says 伺いシャミー (シャミー being the name of a cat). I guess it could just be a typo, but I still don't understand what it's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary form + noun corresponds to the usage of relative clause in English, so you can use it as long as it respects the grammar of the verb.

- 飲む人 a man who drinks
- 酒を飲む人 a man who drinks alcohol
- コーヒーを飲む人 a man who drinks coffee

As for the other pattern, it is not *verb stem* but *masu-form* (without masu) used as a noun (see below). This is called 連用形の名詞化. So grammatically *verb masu-form* + *noun* is a complex noun made by combining two nouns. As is the case with most complex nouns, what combination is natural depends on collocations and there are no easy rules. Ultimately you need to consult dictionaries or depend on intuition.

For example, 飲み人 is not common but certainly understandable and so is 酒飲み人. Both would be understood as a habitual drinker. On the other hand コーヒー飲み人 is odd.

There are more totally common words that have this structure, like 生き方, ゴミ捨て場, 読み仮名.

---

About *masu-form* and *stem*: note they coincide in ichidan verbs. For godan verbs, they are different.

- godan: 走ら-ない, **走り**-ます, 走-る
- ichidan: 生き-ない, **生き**-ます, 生き-る

And compare the relevant nouns: 走り方 and 生き方.

---

(added)

Just to clarify some points discussed in the comment, in the 'dictionary form' usage, you don't have to have it in plain dictionary form. It is more or less constructed in a way similar to English.

> 猫が走る a cat runs 
> → 走る猫 a cat that runs
>
> 猫が外を走る a cat is running outside 
> → 外を走っている猫 a cat that is running outside

> 猫がソファで眠る a cat sleeps on the sofa 
> → ソファで眠る猫 a cat that sleeps on the sofa
>
> 猫がソファで眠っていた a cat was sleeping on the sofa 
> → ソファで眠っていた猫 a cat that was sleeping on the sofa

The *sentence-ending* form may be less confusing to denote the form used in this usage.

Comment: But attributive verbs don't have to be in 辞書形, do they? 仲間だった男・走ってる子供

Comment: @EddieKal I'm not sure what exactly the connotation of 辞書形 is, but normally non-learners' grammar calls it 終止形. It is 辞書形 in the sense that た and る is 終止形.

Comment: The question of what 辞書形 is actually troubled me for a while, because it doesn't seem to have ever been accurately defined anywhere, and yet a lot of authoritative teaching sources, papers, and trained native speaking Japanese teachers all use it. For example, 東京外国語大学言語モジュール's site uses 辞書形 and juxtaposes it with タ形, ます形 etc. It is clearly a learner-friendly and learner-specific concept, as you point out. I think most of us learners see 辞書形 as what's presented in a dictionary, namely the basic form of a verb, and by that token タ形, テ形, テイル形 are not.

Comment: One way it was presented to me is 辞書形 comprises 終止形 and 連体形 in 国文法. Btw, I wonder if you could elaborate on タ形 being 終止形, and I'd appreciate it if you could cite a source, because the sources I have seen exclude タ形 from 終止形. For example, [this paper from 鳥取大学](http://unicorn.ike.tottori-u.ac.jp/1999/matoba/paper/graduation-thesis/node8.html).

Comment: @EddieKal To me, it is kind of ambiguous タ形 includes タ or not (I suppose not, but it sounds like it does). Anyway [た](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%A0/#gsc.tab=0) in だっ**た** or (い)る in 走ってる is in 終止形. That is what I mean 仲間だった or 走ってる is in 終止形. So what matters here is auxiliaries and not verbs.